# Linear Algebra - Proving a projection onto a subspace is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

How do I prove that a projection onto a subspace is a linear transformation ?

Given that V is a vector space, and M is a subspace of V.

I know these two facts:

i) There exists a subspace $N$ such that every vector $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as $v = x + y$ for some $x \in M$ and $y \in N$.

ii) $P$ is given by $P(x + y) = x$, for all $x \in M$ and $y \in N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v=x+y$ and $w=x'+y'$, with $x,x'\in M$ and $y,y'\in N$, then\begin{align}P(v+w)&=P(x+y+x'+y')\\&=P(x+x'+y+y')\\&=x+x'\\&=P(v)+P(w).\end{align}Can you prove now that if $\lambda$ is a scalar, then $P(\lambda v)=\lambda P(v)$?

Comment: Based off what you wrote: $(\lambda v)  = P(\lambda(x + y)) \rightarrow = P(\lambdax + \lambda y) \right arrow = P(\lambdax) + P(\lambda y)  =\rightarrow = \lambda P(x) + \lambda P(y) \rightarrow = \lambda (P(x) + P(y)) \rightarrow = \lambda (P(x + y)) \rightarrow = \lambda P(v)$

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: okay so I showed that it's closed under scalar multiplication and closed under addition. How would I show that it is a zero vector ? P(0) = {0}. And would that be the complete proof of the question ?

Comment: There's nothing else to do. Asserting that $P$ is linear means two things: that $P(v+w)=P(v)+P(w)$ and that $P(\lambda v)=\lambda P(v)$.

Comment: Isn’t it also to show that it contains the zero vector as well ?

Comment: Maps do not contain vectors. You are thinking about the definition of vector space instead of the definition of linear map.

Comment: Riight. Sorry I got mixed up with the two. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to show $P(v_1+v_2)=P(v_1)+P(v_2)$ for $v_1,v_2\in W$,  and $P(\lambda v)=\lambda P(v)$ for $v\in V$, $\lambda\in F$.

Write $v_1=x_1+y_1$, $v_2=x_2+y_2$ with $x_i\in M$, $y_i\in N$, so that $P(v_i)=x_i$. Let $x=x_1+x_2\in M$, $y=y_1+y_2\in N$. Then $v_1+v_2=x+y$, and by uniqueness of this decomposition, $P(v_1+v_2)=x=P(v_1)+P(v_2)$, as desired.

Similarly, if $v=x+y$ with $x\in M$, $y\in N$, then $\lambda v=\lambda x+\lambda y$ with $\lambda x\in M$, $\lambda y\in N$. We conclude that $P(\lambda v)\lambda x=\lambda P(v)$.

Comment: thank you for your response. On the very last line, is it $P(/lambdav/lambdax)$? If not, can you clarify why its $P(/lambdav)/lambdax$

Comment: @JCheong It should be $P(\lambda v)=\lambda x=\lambda P(v)$.