# Proving a projection onto subspace if $P^2 = P$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

Suppose that V is a vector space, and M is a subspace of V . A transformation $P : V \to V$
is called the projection of V onto M if

(i) there exists a subspace N such that every vector v ∈ V can be written uniquely as
$v = x + y$ for some $x ∈ M$ and $y ∈ N$; and

(ii) P is given by $P(x + y) = x$, for all $x ∈ M$ and $y ∈ N$.

Question: Suppose that $P : V \to V$ is a linear transformation. Prove that P is a projection onto
some subspace of V if and only if $P^2 = P$

So I can't seem to prove the reverse direction where I assume P^2 = P. Like what do we need to prove in order to show that it is a projection??

Comment: Does $V$ has finite dimension ?

Comment: yes v has a finite dimension

Comment: I think you should write "a projection of  V onto M", rather than "the projection of V onto M", since the condition does not define a unique P.

Comment: this was the way the question was worded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra - Proving a projection onto a subspace is a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222102/linear-algebra-proving-a-projection-onto-a-subspace-is-a-linear-transformation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the range of $P$ and $N$ be the kernel. Then $x =Px+(x-P(x)), Px \in M$ and $x-Px \in N$ because $P(x-Px)=Px-P^{2}x=0$. Hence every vector is  a sum of an element from $M$ and an element from $N$. Suppose $x+y=u+v$ where $x, u \in M$ and $y,v \in N$. Then we can write $x=Px',u=Pu'$ so $P(x-u)=P^{2}(x'-u')=P(x'-u')=x-u$. But $x-u=v-y$. Applying $P$ to both sides we get $x-u=P(v-y)=Pv-Py=0-0=0$. Hence $x=u$ and it is now obviuous that $v=y$. This proves (i). 
 (ii) is easy: if $x =m+n, m \in M, n \in N$ then $Px=P(m+n)=Pm+0=Pm=m$ since $m =Pz$ for some $z$ which gives $Pm=P^{2}z=Pz=m$.

Comment: hi, why is x the sum of the range and kernel?

Comment: The equation $x=Px+(x-Px)$ is an identity and I have proved that the first term is in $M$ and the second term is in $N$.

Comment: ah ok thank you

Comment: (−)=^2(′−′) how did u get this?

Comment: $Px=P(Px')=P^{2}(x')$ and $Pu=P(Pu')=P^{2}(u')$

Comment: but above you defined $u$ not $y$, is this a typo?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: so by showing x = u and y = v   you showed that v can be written uniquely by showing that the linear combinations of the same vector must be the same?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: =+(−), is there a specific name to this identity or source to further read about?

Comment: As  far as I know there is no name for it but it is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: since $P^2=P$, we have $(1-P)^2=1-P$ and $P(1-P)=0$. Now, write any $v$ as $v = Pv + (1-P)v$.